# jQuery — Variable comparison that just doesn't work

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, tumblr

EDIT: I've put this in a document ready function.
The images are big though, does document ready comply with large images?
you can see it not working here: http://syndex.me

This is driving me quietly insane.

```
var maxxxHeight = $(window).height();

$(".theImage").children('img').each(function() {
  myHeight = $(this).height();
      if ( myHeight > maxxxHeight ){
      $(this).next().text("Browser " + maxxxHeight + " image height " + myHeight);
  };
});
```

For some reason,

> myHeight > maxxxHeight will not come up with anyhing. There are images whose sizes are bigger, and some not. The images are not being set by CSS. Their width and height are not specified at any point in fact.

How can this be? This is a total noob question, but i'v done if's and  < / > a million times before.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several reasons this might be happening.

1. The images may not yet be completely loaded at the time the code runs.
2. Your images may not be direct children of the element matching your class.
3. Your code may be running before the document is loaded and nothing matches the class yet.

My best guess is (1), in which case you should add a load handler for the images that does what you want when the image completes loading. Running the code on both document load and image load is probably in order in case the image is cached and the load event for it fires before the image load handler is applied.  Image load would be necessary if the image is replaced dynamically after the document has been loaded.

**NOTE**: You should be scoping myHeight locally to avoid polluting the global namespace (and potential bugs due to scoping issues).

```
$(document).load( function() {
    var maxxxHeight = $(window).height();

    $(".theImage").children('img').each(function() {
        $(this).load( function() { // only if images can be loaded dynamically
            handleImageLoad(this);
        });
        handleImageLoad(this);
    });

    function handleImageLoad(img)
    {
        var $img = $(img),  // declare local and cache jQuery for the argument
            myHeight = $img.height();
        if ( myHeight > maxxxHeight ){
           // this is where your real code would go to make adjustments, etc.
           $img.next().text("Browser " + maxxxHeight + " image height " + myHeight);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: I fixed that var scope. I do get image height being "0". I just don't understand why that could be. In my css I now have height and width for img { as "auto".

Comment: @RGBK if the image isn't loaded yet when the code runs, the element has no height.  Try running the code on document load instead of document ready.  `$(document).load( function() { ... } );`

Comment: Ok, but actually, i should then look at the height of the div that is loading it, which should have an idea of how big it will be if it knows how big the image will be? Isn't their meta data about the image without me having to specify it for each image, inline or via css?

Comment: It cant be that the browser only knows how big an image is once it's loaded all those pixels?!

Comment: @RGBK the DIV won't have size (unless you set it) until it's content is loaded.  The browser doesn't know how big the image is until it is rendered (metadata may lie) unless you specify it and then it will scale the image to fit your size.

Comment: That's an awesome solution. I've tried to understand what you're doing there. The only thing that;s beyond me is the var $img = $(img), is the $(img) the same as handleImageLoad(img)? And then the $img is a special variable for cache? When else would you need to do this trick? Thanks so much!

Comment: `$img` is just caching the result of `$(img)` in a variable so that you can reuse it instead of have jQuery look it up each time.

Comment: Ack, I've just run into a new issue, as it's using an infinite scroll i need to put this (i think) in a "live." I tried this out by doing something like $(".theImage").children('img').live("each",function(){ {but it breaks the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some debugging. Since the comparison is failing, check the values of myHeight and maxxxHeight by printing them to the console. I guarantee that one of those two is not a number. In fact, one will probably be undefined.

And are you putting your jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready()` call?